# Get only the selected options in the carousel

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I've got an **owl carousel** where i have this structure:

```
<div id="comidas" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <a class="item opcion" >
        <img class="img" src = "/path/to/image.jpg" alt = "Image Name" item-id="2" >
    </a >
    <a class="item opcion" >
        <img class="img" src = "/path/to/image.jpg" alt = "Image Name" item-id="3">
    </a >
</div>
```

And when i click on one of the items i add a class `clicked` to the `a` element, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#comidas").owlCarousel({
        items : 10
    });

    $('.opcion').on('click', function(event){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.hasClass('clicked')){
            $this.removeAttr('style').removeClass('clicked');
            $this.children('img').removeClass('selected-option');
        } else{
            $this.addClass('clicked');
            $this.children('img').addClass('selected-option');
        }
    });

});
```

What i would like to know is how could i make a new carousel only with the **clicked** items right after a specific element in the view?

What i was thinking was on loop through all the elements inside the `div` and then `.insertAfter` a element the new carousel... but how?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `owlCarousel` plugin, but I guess you could create a new div, append all `.clicked` items and then `$myNewDiv.owlCarousel({...})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want add those `clicked` items when you click a button, you can loop through the items and add it to the selected element.. I make a similar case on [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5w70ebqd/), hope it helps.

```
<div id="source">
    <!-- assuming this is your carousel -->
    <div class="option" ><a>1</a></div>
    <div class="option" ><a>2</a></div>
    <div class="option" ><a>3</a></div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn-execute" value="execute" />
```

jQuery

```
$(".option").on("click",function(){
    //this works like your code above
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('clicked')){
        $this.removeClass('clicked');
    } else{
        $this.addClass('clicked');
    }
});

$("#btn-execute").click(function(){
    var btn_element = $(this);
    //this is how you loop through your item and add it to a specific element
    $(".option").each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("clicked")){
            $("<div>"+$(this).html()+"</div>").insertAfter(btn_element);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what i need, but there's something missing i didn't specified, the new carousel will be created when the button is clicked... so that means a new `<div id="source">
    <div class="option" ><a>3</a></div>
   <div class="option" ><a>3</a></div>
</div>`  will be created...

Comment: @JonathanS. You didn't mention the Ajax on your question, do you? I use button for triggering that function, since you didn't mention when the selected items would be added..

Comment: Sorry, I didnt, but could you please help me with that? This is the right answer to the question, but I have a problem in my app because it's under laravel

Comment: @JonathanS. I don't really know what you want in ajax. If you can't find the answer here, you may post another question so it might be useful for others too.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(".clicked")` returns an array of elements that have the class "clicked". With this, you can make another carousel and loop through the returned array and use .append(element) to add each clicked image to the new carousel.

Comment: Maybe if you could make an example i would see if it's what i need

Comment: @jonathan-s Try out http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epOZyL
I've made it able to either copy or move the element at the press of the corresponding button.